# Converting an XTS object to a data.frame

Tags: r, xts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a variable of rownames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427434/how-to-create-a-variable-of-rownames)

---

Please run it in  R:

```
require(quantmod)   
setSymbolLookup(SDB=list(name="000001.sz",src="yahoo"))   
getSymbols("SDB",from="2010-01-01",to="2010-02-01")   
sdb=as.data.frame(weeklyReturn(SDB))  
sdb
```

What I get is:

```
           weekly.returns             
2010-01-08    -0.07830343          
2010-01-15    -0.05176991              
2010-01-22     0.07699487              
2010-01-29    -0.05979203         
2010-02-01    -0.02119816
```

What I want to get is:

```
        date  weekly.returns                   
1 2010-01-08     -0.07830343           
2 2010-01-15     -0.05176991         
3 2010-01-22      0.07699487          
4 2010-01-29     -0.05979203            
5 2010-02-01     -0.02119816
```

How can I do this?

Note that this is an `XTS` object, not a basic `data.frame`. After the conversion, I want the original rownames to appear as a new variable in the resulting `data.frame`.

Comment: How is this any different from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427434/how-to-create-a-variable-of-rownames)?

Comment: sdb2=data.frame(date=row.names(sdb), weekly.returns=sdb$weekly.returns)

Comment: @mrdwab My mistake, and apologies to user1142618.

Answer (score 14):

Ok. So, it's not exactly the same as your earlier question since this is an `XTS` object. Still, very easy to take care of:

```
data.frame(date = index(weeklyReturn(SDB)), 
           weeklyReturn(SDB), row.names=NULL)
#         date weekly.returns
# 1 2010-01-04    -0.03303426
# 2 2010-01-11    -0.04681569
# 3 2010-01-18    -0.05000000
# 4 2010-01-25     0.03353517
# 5 2010-02-01    -0.04281208
```

For help on what is being done here, view use `?indexClass` to read the documentation for `index` in the `XTS` package.