# Correct the format of my function output

Tags: r

Here is my function to calculate beta for the China stock market:

```
mybeta <- function(company) {
  require(quantmod)
  setSymbolLookup(CSI300=list(name="000300.ss",src="yahoo"))
  getSymbols("CSI300",from="2010-01-01",to="2011-01-01")
  setSymbolLookup(SDB=list(name=company,src="yahoo"))
  getSymbols("SDB",from="2010-01-01",to="2011-01-01")
  csi=as.data.frame(weeklyReturn(CSI300))
  sdb=as.data.frame(weeklyReturn(SDB))
  cbeta=merge(csi, sdb, by="row.names")
  cov(cbeta[2],cbeta[3])/var(cbeta[2])
}
```

when i input:

```
mybeta("600005.ss")
                  weekly.returns.y
weekly.returns.x          1.105631
```

I only want the `1.105631` from the output, not the "weekly.returns.y" and "weekly.returns.x".  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

It's clear English isn't your first language, so I will be patient.

You have revealed what you are actually trying to do, so your first two questions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11427434/271616), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11429889/271616)) could have been avoided because they are not useful for solving your actual problem.

Here is a modified version of your function that accomplishes the same goal, with a lot less unnecessary work.

```
mybeta <- function(company) {
  if(!require(quantmod))
    stop("quantmod must be installed; try install.packages('quantmod')")
  setSymbolLookup(CSI300=list(name="000300.ss",src="yahoo"), 
                  SDB=list(name=company,src="yahoo"))
  getSymbols(c("CSI300","SDB"),from="2010-01-01",to="2011-01-01")
  ret <- merge(weeklyReturn(CSI300),weeklyReturn(SDB))
  cbeta <- cov(ret, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
  cbeta[1,2]/cbeta[1,1]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `as.numeric`

Make the last line of your function

```
as.numeric(cov(cbeta[2],cbeta[3])/var(cbeta[2]))
```

As an aside, there is no reason to be using `data.frame`s here.  `xts` is awesome; embrace it.

Edit:
In addition to not needing to convert to `data.frame`, it's probably safer for your function to not have side-effects (for example, `getSymbols("SDB")` would return a different value depending on what you passed to `mybeta` last; also, `getSymbols` assigns data in your `.GlobalEnv` by default.  You might consider using `auto.assign=FALSE`.  This is how I would edit your function:

```
mybeta <- function(company) {
  require("quantmod")
  CSI300 <- getSymbols("000300.ss", src='yahoo', from="2010-01-01", 
                       to="2011-01-01", auto.assign=FALSE)
  SDB <- getSymbols(company, src='yahoo', from="2010-01-01", to="2011-01-01", 
                    auto.assign=FALSE)
  csi <- weeklyReturn(CSI300)
  sdb <- weeklyReturn(SDB)
  cbeta=merge(csi, sdb)
  as.numeric(cov(cbeta[, 1], cbeta[, 2])/var(cbeta[, 1]))
}
```