# Converting an xts object to a useful data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

A dataframe named d contains this data:

```
timestamp,value
"2013-06-02 00:00:00",70
"2013-06-02 00:02:00",70
"2013-06-02 00:07:00",60
"2013-06-02 00:15:00",70
"2013-06-02 00:12:00",60
"2013-06-02 00:30:00",70
"2013-06-02 00:45:00",70
"2013-06-02 01:00:00",70
```

The code I have is:

```
 d = read.csv(path, header=TRUE, sep=",")
 d2 <- xts(x = d[c("value")], order.by = as.POSIXct(d[, "timestamp"], tz = "GMT", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
ends <- endpoints(d2, on = "minutes", k = 15)
d3   <- period.apply(d2, ends, mean)
```

After that I want to convert the xts object to the dataframe and I am using this:

```
d3$timestamp = rownames(d3)
rownames(d3) = NULL
d3$timestamp = strptime(d3$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

However in the last step it prints error to this:

```
Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : 
   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

As I observe typing d3 after the whole commands the object has this format of data:

```
                         timestamp
2013-06-02 00:15:00        65
2013-06-02 00:30:00        70
2013-06-02 00:45:00        70
2013-06-02 01:00:00        70
```

However in the column name it must have the name value and as the second column have the timestamp like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427434/how-to-create-a-variable-of-rownames/11427568#11427568). What could be wrong?

The right output must be this:

```
      value
        65  2013-06-02 00:15:00
        70  2013-06-02 00:30:00
        70  2013-06-02 00:45:00
        70  2013-06-02 01:00:00
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create your data.frame like this for example :

```
 data.frame(value=coredata(d3),timestamp=index(d3))
# value           timestamp
# 1    65 2013-06-02 00:12:00
# 2    70 2013-06-02 00:15:00
# 3    70 2013-06-02 00:30:00
# 4    70 2013-06-02 00:45:00
# 5    70 2013-06-02 01:00:00
```

I advise you also to use `read.zoo` to read your data as a zoo object and avoid coercing xts by hand. For example:

```
dat <- read.zoo(text='timestamp,value
"2013-06-02 00:00:00",70
"2013-06-02 00:02:00",70
"2013-06-02 00:07:00",60
"2013-06-02 00:15:00",70
"2013-06-02 00:12:00",60
"2013-06-02 00:30:00",70
"2013-06-02 00:45:00",70
"2013-06-02 01:00:00",70',tz ='' , format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",header=TRUE,
         sep=',')
d2 <- as.xts(dat)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the `tidyquant` package which as two functions useful for coercing (converting) data frames to and from xts objects: namely `as_xts()` for converting data frames to xts, and `as_tibble()` for converting xts (and other time series or matrix objects) to "tidy" data frames.

Here's a quick example. I use the `tribble()` function to recreate your example. During the conversion process, I use the `as_datetime()` function from `lubridate` (`tidyquant` loads this automatically) to convert from character to date-time class. Everything else should be pretty straightforward.

```r
library(tidyquant)

# Recreate data frame
data_df <- tribble(
    ~timestamp, ~value,
    "2013-06-02 00:00:00", 70,
    "2013-06-02 00:02:00", 70,
    "2013-06-02 00:07:00", 60,
    "2013-06-02 00:15:00", 70,
    "2013-06-02 00:12:00", 60,
    "2013-06-02 00:30:00", 70,
    "2013-06-02 00:45:00", 70,
    "2013-06-02 01:00:00", 70
)
data_df
#> # A tibble: 8 Ã— 2
#>             timestamp value
#>                 <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 2013-06-02 00:00:00    70
#> 2 2013-06-02 00:02:00    70
#> 3 2013-06-02 00:07:00    60
#> 4 2013-06-02 00:15:00    70
#> 5 2013-06-02 00:12:00    60
#> 6 2013-06-02 00:30:00    70
#> 7 2013-06-02 00:45:00    70
#> 8 2013-06-02 01:00:00    70

# Convert data frame to xts
data_xts <- data_df %>%
    mutate(timestamp = as_datetime(timestamp, tz = Sys.timezone())) %>%
    as_xts(date_col = timestamp)
data_xts
#>                     value
#> 2013-06-02 00:00:00    70
#> 2013-06-02 00:02:00    70
#> 2013-06-02 00:07:00    60
#> 2013-06-02 00:12:00    60
#> 2013-06-02 00:15:00    70
#> 2013-06-02 00:30:00    70
#> 2013-06-02 00:45:00    70
#> 2013-06-02 01:00:00    70

# Convert xts to data frame
data_df_2 <- data_xts %>%
    as_tibble(preserve_row_names = TRUE) %>%
    rename(timestamp = row.names) %>%
    mutate(timestamp = as_datetime(timestamp, tz = Sys.timezone()))
data_df_2
#> # A tibble: 8 Ã— 2
#>             timestamp value
#>                <dttm> <dbl>
#> 1 2013-06-02 00:00:00    70
#> 2 2013-06-02 00:02:00    70
#> 3 2013-06-02 00:07:00    60
#> 4 2013-06-02 00:12:00    60
#> 5 2013-06-02 00:15:00    70
#> 6 2013-06-02 00:30:00    70
#> 7 2013-06-02 00:45:00    70
#> 8 2013-06-02 01:00:00    70
```

Comment: Note that `timetk::tk_xt()` and `timetk::tk_tbl()` are replacing `tidyquant::as_xts()` and `tidyquant::as_tibble()`. Please switch over to the `timetk` package for these coercion operations.